# ASP.NET/MVC5 <sessionState> timeout configuration being ignored

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, session-state, session-timeout

I have been trying to set my web application session-timeout to 90 minutes without success.

In my web.config I have it set as follow:

```
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="90"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
```

... but the session keeps timing out at 20 minutes (default value).

Any insight on how to trace this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The default idle timeout for a worker process is also 20 minutes.  Since you are using InProc, it is likely this timer that is causing the timeout.  Switch to ProcServer or SqlServer or better yet quit using the ASP.Net Session all together.